# Randomly getting error screen on iPad device when using a custom lightning component functionality

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, ipad

We have custom functionality built using lightning components and apex classes. This functionality works properly on desktop device, however, when used with iPad, give "Sorry to interrupt" error screen randomly.

[image]
[image]

Note that logic of this functionality is working as expected but it's just that this screen appears randomly when used on iPad device

Any help will be appreciated.